# Quadratic residues and euler equation

Tags: elementary-number-theory, congruences, quadratic-residues, legendre-symbol

Let $p$ be an odd prime and let $(a,p)=1$.
There is no guaranteed that there is a solution to $$x^2\equiv a \pmod p$$

What is wrong here:
$$a^{(p-1)/2}≡(x^2)^{(p-1)/2}\equiv x^{p-1} \pmod p$$

It is known that $(a,p)=1$, so $(x,p)=1$; then we get:

$$a^{(p-1)/2}\equiv x^{p-1}\equiv 1\pmod p$$

so I just proved that every $a$ is QR even if it is not. Well that is just wrong.

Where am I wrong here?

Comment: In what has been written above I do not see a proof that every $a$ is a QR. The $x$ exists only if $a$ is a QR.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The existence of an $x$ with $$a^{(p-1)/2}\equiv (x^2)^{(p-1)/2}$$ modulo $p$ cannot be assumed if $x^2\equiv a$ modulo $p$ has no solution.

In fact, if $a$ is no quadratic residue modulo $p$ and $(a,p)=1$, then $$a^{(p-1)/2}\equiv -1$$ modulo $p$ holds.

Comment: Euler's theorem states $$(a,p)=1\rightarrow a^{(p-1)/2} \equiv (\frac{a}{p})$$ modulo $p$, where $(\frac{a}{p})$ is the legendre symbol.